# Passing array by reference without explicitly stating the size of the array in function declaration

Tags: c++

I wonder if it is possible to pass an array or std::array to a function by reference, without explicitly stating the size of the array in function declaration, that is something in this fashion void Foo(std::array& 
arr).

```
const int n = 4;
std::array<int, n> arr;
Foo(arr, n);
void Foo( std::array<int, n>& arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that because `std::array`s of different sizes are distinct types.

Either make it a function template as per aparpara's answer, or make it a function template that accepts a range as a pair of iterators. The latter option would make it independent of the container type and the element type. This is also consistent with the way the standard library does it:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void Foo(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to make the function template:

```
template <typename T, int N>
void Foo(std::array<T, N>& arr)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: your proposed solution doesn't answer the question answered, which was " **I wonder if it is possible to pass an array or std::array to a function by reference, without explicitly stating the size of the array in function declaration** "

Comment: @eapetcho The size is not explicit as you don't specify `std::array<int, 4>` for example in which case the function would be limited to that specific type. The size is deduced automatically by the compiler which is a totally different thing.  Also, that would work perfectly with the code provided in the question.